# How to enable autocomplete for personal script?

Tags: linux, bash

I added my script to /usr/bin, and it runs as expected if I type the full command name. How do I get the terminal to autocomplete the command name?

Comment: how do you run your script? did you set the execution permission?

Comment: Yes, execution permission is provided.

Answer (score 3):

```
hash -r
```

or open a new shell.

When your shell starts up, it scans your `PATH` and caches the names and locations of programs it finds; when you ask it to run a program, it then checks its cache first and if it finds the location there it doesn't have to scan all the directories in your path, which is fairly time consuming.  Bash uses the results of the initial scan for command tab-completion (and doesn't update it when you run a new program), so your program won't make it into there until you open a new session or tell it to rehash the path.

N.b. for future answer-seekers: in zsh, use `rehash`

Comment: It’s `rehash` in `csh`, too.